# Question on prediction using Seq2seq model with embedding layers

Tags: tensorflow, embedding, seq2seq

I am a newbie in tensorflow and Seq2seq. When I wrote a code for Seq2Seq model with embedding layers based on others' codes with no embedding layers, I got errors when using the trained model to predict values.

Here are the codes for my Seq2Seq model:

```
# Build encoder
encoder_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,))
encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=max_eng_vocabulary,
    output_dim=embedding_output_length,
    mask_zero=True,
)
encoder_input_1 = encoder_embedding(encoder_input)
encoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_input_1)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Build decoder model
decoder_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=max_chi_vocabulary,
    output_dim=embedding_output_length,
    mask_zero=True,
)
decoder_input_1 = decoder_embedding(decoder_input)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
    50,
    return_state=True,
    return_sequences=True,
)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_input_1, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(max_chi_vocabulary, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Combine the encoder and decoder
model = tf.keras.Model([encoder_input, decoder_input], decoder_outputs)
```

When I tried to use it for prediction, the code is similar with this:

```
model.predict([encoder_input_data[0], decoder_input_data[0]])
```

The input set in the above code is exactly one of the data sets in the training data set. After running the prediction code, I got errors: `Layer lstm_1 expects 7 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'model/embedding_1/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0' shape=(None, 1, 100) dtype=float32>]`

A sketch of the model structure is also attached.

[Model Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GYMm.png)

I have an additional question: it seems the masking function for the embeddings doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with my model definition?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error is because of the environment. Using Colab leads to no error.